# MySQL Region/Country Relationships and Normalization

Tags: mysql, normalization

I am creating relationships to Region, Sub_Region, Country and Country_Regions.

The reason I want 4 layers is for narrowing searches.  For instance, the landing page will have a Google Map with the whole world, you can click on any Region (Continent), that zooms to that continent with its Sub_Regions, click a Sub_Region to get the Countries, and if the country has Country_Regions, it will zoom to those...

My problem is not all Region/Country relationships have a Sub_Region.

An example of a Sub_Region is

```
Region    |    Sub_Region         |    Country        |    Country_Region
Caribbean |    Lesser Antilles    |    Saint Martin   |    NULL
Europe    |    Iberian Peninsula  |    Spain          |    NULL
```

The problem is if I try to put the United States into this structure, it looks like this:

```
Region         |    Sub_Region         |    Country         |    Country_Region
North America  |    NULL               |    United States   |    Southeast
```

How can I normalize this so that if there is no Sub_Region, or Country_Region, the data is still consistent and InnoDB will be happy and help me with the references?

Comment: You're mixing things that are probably better unmixed. For example, "North America" has to do with physical geography, but "United States" has to do with political geography. Your life gets simpler if you pick one. Also, some countries consist of countries. (Not a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

Normalization should be like below :

table 1:

**region**

```
id | region_name
```

table 2:

**country**

```
id | country_name | region_id
```

table 3:

**region_type**

```
 id | region_type  (Southeast,Southwest etc)
```

table 4:

**sub region**

```
 id | sub_region  | country_id | region_type_id
```

Comment: wouldn't i need a sub_region table as well to make it a 3NF?

Comment: see updated . do u want to save country region with each sub region also ?

Comment: This is totally different than what the OP asks. This design means a country can have many regions. When the OP says `Region` he means `Continent`.

Comment: where I'm running into problems is the optional Sub_Region column.  Am I over complicating this?

Comment: @Teez The relations are A region can have many or no Sub_Regions, a Sub_Region can have many Countries, Countries can have many or no Country_Regions... I would imagine there would be a table for each of the 4 categories to make it as normalized as possible

Comment: @Teez Sub_Region is a child of Regions and Country_Region is a child of Country.  I'm not trying to be difficult, but in either model, yours or mine, don't see how I can keep Sub_Regions optional.. Maybe I'm just blind to what I'm asking lol

Answer (score 0):

Hava all your location information in just a table, and put them in a tree structure

```
table location (
    id,
    title,
    location_type,
    fk_loc_parent,
)
```

Comment: I will definitely give this a try.